# Is this a retain cycle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I usually get a warning when I call anything on self in a block retained by self:

```
[self.someView doSomething:^{
        self.aVar = @"Hello!";
    }];
```

I have to do:

```
        __weak SomeObject *weakSelf = self;
[self.someView doSomething:^{
        weakSelf.aVar = @"Hello!";
    }];
```

But if I call a method on weakSelf, and that method uses self, will that lead to a retain cycle even though I don't get a warning? I am talking about this:

```
        __weak SomeObject *weakSelf = self;
[self.someView doSomething:^{
        weakSelf.aVar = @"Hello!";
        [weakSelf aMethod];
    }];
```

and aMethod uses `self`

Comment: Ohhh. Still worrying about retain cycle?

Comment: Retain cycles still exist in ARC-land.

Comment: @trojanfoe: Yes I agree, In this situation it is weak referneced under ARC... even then?

Comment: @AKV ARC isn't garbage collection. You _should_ worry about retain cycles.

Comment: @AKV Retain Cycles are very possible in ARC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as your `weakSelf` is [declared outside your block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14479824/2998), there is no retain cycle.

Use of objects inside the block implicitly increments the retain count. But you'd be calling `aMethod` on *`weakSelf`* rather than `self`, so the retain count is not affected.

Comment: Cool, thanks! Just wanted to make sure maybe it's an indirect retain cycle because aMethod is using self.*

Comment: Is that what @rckoenes answered 11 minutes before you did Stephen?

Comment: @trojanfoe When I answered it his answer didn't address the question, though it did highlight an important issue (which is why I linked to it).

Comment: @trojanfoe reckoenes answered my question after stephen. The issue he highlighted initially was a typo.

Answer (score 2):

You should declare the `__weak` to `self` outside of your block:

```
__weak SomeObject *weakSelf = self;
[self.someView doSomething:^{
     weakSelf.aVar = @"Hello!";
     [weakSelf aMethod];
}];
```

Else the compiler would have already retained self since it is used with the block.

Beter even is using the `__block` directive, because `__weak` is iOS 5 and higher only.

```
__block SomeObject *weakSelf = self;
[self.someView doSomething:^{
     weakSelf.aVar = @"Hello!";
     [weakSelf aMethod];
}];
```

About an other method calling self and causing retain, I've never seen this behavior. I always use the `__block` directive which might catch that one as well.

Comment: Yes i know, that's what I meant sorry. Was writing from within SO (rather than copy pasting from XCode) and completely forgot about that.

Comment: Better is `SomeObject * __weak weakSelf = self;`, although the compiler will forgive you.

Comment: @rckoenes thanks but could you shed some light on my original questions: Does calling a method from weakSelf when that method uses self (not weakSelf) cause a retain cycle even though the compiler doesn't generate a warning?

Comment: @0xSina Because that's how the variable qualifier is supposed to be defined, however the compiler is forgiving.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your "even better" part. Unless you're targetting iOS 4 I think `__weak` is the way to go as it documents what you're trying to do. `__block` does something else; the "weak" part is (sort of) a side-effect.

Comment: if im not wrong you have to set `weakSelf` to `nil` at the end of the block if you are using `__block` to avoid retain cycles.